# Export Cookie Jar to JSON with Node Request

Tags: node.js, cookies, request

The `request` documentation talks about importing cookies from a file with the following example:

```
var FileCookieStore = require('tough-cookie-filestore');
// NOTE - currently the 'cookies.json' file must already exist!
var j = request.jar(new FileCookieStore('cookies.json'));
request = request.defaults({ jar : j })
request('http://www.google.com', function() {
  request('http://images.google.com')
})
```

However, as noted in the comment, it expects `cookies.json` to already exist. The question is, if I have an exsting jar with cookies in it, how can I export it to JSON?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure to understand what you mean by "if I have an exsting jar with cookies in it", but here is how I manage persistent cookies with nodejs.

To avoid errors with `FileCookieStore`, I add a piece of code to create the json file if it does not exist. The file can be empty, as long as it exists:

```
if(!fs.existsSync(cookiepath)){
    fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(cookiepath, 'w'));
}
```

Now, if you look closely at the `FileCookieStore` code, you will see it calls the `saveToFile` method anytime there is a change in the cookies. It means that by passing a `FileCookieStore` object to the `request` module (using the `jar` option as [the request documentation](https://github.com/request/request) explains), the json file will always reflect the state of the cookies.

Here is a complete example:

```
var FileCookieStore = require('tough-cookie-filestore');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require("fs");

var cookiepath = "cookies.json";

// create the json file if it does not exist
if(!fs.existsSync(cookiepath)){
    fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(cookiepath, 'w'));
}

// use the FileCookieStore with the request package
var jar = request.jar(new FileCookieStore(cookiepath));
request = request.defaults({ jar : jar });

// do whatever you want
request('http://www.google.com', function() {
    request('http://images.google.com')
});

// the cookies in 'jar' corresponds to the cookies in cookies.json
console.log(jar);
```

To start anew, simply delete the `cookipath` file.

Comment: Ah, the piece of information I was missing here was the request module updating the filestore when cookies change. I thought I needed to export the cookies manually to the file. Thanks for the explanation and example.