# Why is my Promise returning undefined in main.js from a module export?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jar, promise, resolve

Trying to learn how to work with Promises and Async. I can send an object to a module but for some reason I continue to get an `undefined` when processing the `return`. I've narrowed it down to either my return on my module is incorrect or I'm coding something wrong on my Async.

*main.js*

```
ipcMain.on('file-object', (e, res) => {
  module.exports.res = res
  console.log('Starting main.js') 
  async function findTest() {
    const testResult = await valid.jsonTest()
    console.log(testResult)
    mainWindow.webContents.send('test-results', testResult)
  }
  findTest()
})
```

*foobar.js*

```
module.exports = {
    jsonTest: function() {
        let testPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {          
            child = exec('/usr/bin/java -jar ' + jarFile + ' ' + res.res.path, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
                if (stderr !== "") {
                    resolve(
                        resultArray = {
                            "status": "error",
                            "response": stderr
                        }
                    )
                } else {
                    resolve(stdout)
                }
            })
        })
        testPromise.then((successMessage) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(successMessage))
            return successMessage
        })
    }
}
```

After searching and reading several Q&As I've also tried:

```
let foobar = valid.jsonTest()
waitForElement()
function waitForElement() {
    if (typeof foobar !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Getting results')
        console.log(foobar)
        mainWindow.webContents.send('test-results', foobar)
        return 
    }
    else {
        console.log(foobar)
        setTimeout(waitForElement, 1000)
    }
}
```

but I get a continuous `undefined` which is why I think I might be incorrectly returning the module. Also tried:

```
let validationMessage = valid.jsonTest()

console.log("Starting main.js")
let resultPromise = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log('entering promise')
        resolve()
        console.log(`Status results: ${status}`)
    })
}
Promise.resolve().then(() => resultPromise(
    console.log(validationMessage.status)
))
```

Research references from my quieres:

- [node.js call external exe and wait for output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538825/node-js-call-external-exe-and-wait-for-output)
- [What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)
- [Best way to return an exported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54074974/best-way-to-return-an-exported-module)
- [How to make a function wait until a callback has been called using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010288/how-to-make-a-function-wait-until-a-callback-has-been-called-using-node-js)
- [How to return data from promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533929/how-to-return-data-from-promise)
- [Export Cookie Jar to JSON with Node Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053091/export-cookie-jar-to-json-with-node-request)
- [node.js call external exe and wait for output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538825/node-js-call-external-exe-and-wait-for-output)
- [node.js resolve promise and return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453982/node-js-resolve-promise-and-return-value)

How can I send an object to a file, process that object, return and get the result because I'm missing something here and I do not understand why I get undefined and my Promise continues.